# Converting Array to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, type-conversion, ienumerable

To my surprise, I get the following statement:

```
public static IEnumerable<SomeType> AllEnums 
  => Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeType));
```

to complain about not being able to convert from *System.Array* to *System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable*. I thought that the latter was inheriting from the former. Apparently I was mistaken.

Since I can't LINQ it or *.ToList* it, I'm not sure how to deal with it properly. I'd prefer avoiding explicit casting and, since it's a bunch of values for an *enum*, I don't think *as SomeType*-ing it will be of much use, neither.

Comment: `Enum.GetValues` returns an `Array` which is not strongly-typed. So no surprise here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The general `Array` base class is not typed, so it does not implement any type-specific interfaces; however, a *vector* can be cast directly - and `GetValues` actually returns a vector; so:

```
public static IEnumerable<SomeType> AllEnums
    = (SomeType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeType));
```

or perhaps simpler:

```
public static SomeType[] AllEnums 
    = (SomeType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeType));
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that with an Array type rather than enum?

Comment: @toughQuestions it should work for any covariant array type (which isn't quite all arrays) - do you have a specific example?

Comment: Not sure I should place that in the comment section, but say you had the method "IEnumerable  CheckRange(IEnumerable value)". The method needs to check and limit "value". So if we convert "value as Array", then modify value, I then cannot "GetValues" and return it as an IEnumerable as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @toughQuestions are you looking for `.Cast<T>()` /  `.OfType<T>()` ?

Answer (score 5):

> I thought that the latter was inheriting from the former.

`Enum.GetValues` returns `Array`, which implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`, so you need to add a cast:

```
public static IEnumerable<SomeType> AllEnums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeType))
    .Cast<SomeType>()
    .ToList();
```

This works with LINQ because `Cast<T>` extension method is defined for the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, not only on `IEnumerable<U>`.

**Edit:** A call of `ToList()` avoid inefficiency associated with walking multiple times an `IEnumerable<T>` produced by LINQ methods with deferred execution. Thanks, Marc, for a great comment!

Comment: This will be boxing and unboxing whenever it is accessed, note.

Comment: Note that you can cast the result of `Enum.GetValues` directly to `IEnumerable<SomeType>`, there's no need to use `Cast<>`