# JSON to C# -- list fields without sub-field names in json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Using Json.net (Newtonsoft.json), how can I define a C# class (or classes) to handle the json below?

The 'data' field appears to be a list of level/description sub-fields but note they are **not** preceded by field names.

The 'error' field appears to be a list of error-number/error-message sub-fields but note, they too, are **not** preceded by field names.

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "data": [
    {
       "warning" : "your input was wrong"
    }
  ],
  "error": [
    {
      "373": "Error description goes here"
    }
  ]
}
```

This class definition does not generate parsing errors; however the contents of Data and Errors is not correct.

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public string Status;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Errors;
};

// this doesn't throw a parsing exception, but the resulting
// Data and Errors fields are not correctly populated.
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(SampleJson);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This might assist you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744199/converting-array-to-ienumerablet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try defining your `Data` and `Errors` members as IEnumerables of Dictionaries rather than IEnumerables of KeyValuePairs.  (Json.Net expects KeyValuePairs to be represented in JSON as objects with explicit `Key` and `Value` properties, which is not what you have there.)

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public string Status;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> Data;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<int, string>> Errors;
};
```

You can then read the data out using a `foreach` loop with `SelectMany`:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(SampleJson);
foreach (var kvp in x.Data.SelectMany(d => d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
}
foreach (var kvp in x.Errors.SelectMany(d => d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KJuAPu

Comment: Switching to using Dictionary<> works better than KeyValuePair.  My concern with using Dictionary is that the Data field appears as though it could have multiple "warnings".  Errors field appears to be a good fit as I assume the error number would only appear once.

Comment: It will still work with this structure.  Using `SelectMany` will allow you to get everything regardless of how many dictionaries are in each array or how many entries are in each dictionary.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mLZBec

Comment: I see that now.  I was thinking it was just a Dictionary.  It is not, it is an IEnumerable<Dictionary<...>>.  Basically a list of single entry dictionaries.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There are few issues with the class you have created. As per the provide JSON, you should be creating your classes similar like following code.

```
 public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "warning")]
        public string Warning { get; set; }
    }
    public class Error
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "373")]
        public string Col_373 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApiResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
        public List<Error> Error { get; set; }
    }
```

Once you have designed the structure like this, you can always get it back to your object structure as following code snippet. It seems, you are getting confused with the property names and values.

```
 string json = "{\"status\":\"error\", \"data\": [{\"warning\" : \"your input was wrong\" }],  \"error\": [{\"373\": \"Error description goes here\"}]}";

 var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(json);
```

One more observation.

> **"373"**: "Error description goes here"

Please don't use number as the key/column name.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP has control over the JSON-- this is probably a third-party API.  That being the case, your solution will not work if the error code happens to be something other than `373`, or the data is something other than `warning`.  You need something that can handle variable key names.

Comment: @BrianRogers you are correct, i don't control the JSON.

Comment: @Tony Have a look at my answer then; it should work with your JSON and can handle variable key names.